# How many page table levels does Linux kernel use? 4 or 5?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory

[This](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html) article says that Linux uses three-level page tables.

However, in the book *[Professional Linux Kernel Architecture](http://cse.yeditepe.edu.tr/~kserdaroglu/spring2014/cse331/termproject/BOOKS/ProfessionalLinuxKernelArchitecture-WolfgangMauerer.pdf)*, in chapter 3.3.1, it says that Linux uses five-level page tables.

Also, [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/717293/) article says ' The merging of five-level page tables (outside of the merge window) for 4.11-rc2, instead, barely raised an eyebrow.'

My question is how many page table levels does Kernel actually use? If it changed in the history, which version?

Comment: It depends upon the kernel version and the processor

Comment: PLKA describes **4** levels. That's how it was for over a decade, as you can read in the LWN article you cite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is, this is dependent on both kernel version, and processor architecture (because you have to have support in hardware for a given number of page tables).  On 32-bit x86 without PAE, it's 2 levels.  On 32-bit x86 with PAE it's 3 levels.  On 64-bit x86, it's usually 4 levels, but support for 5 got merged recently (however, only really high-end Intel server processors support this, and only very recent ones).  On 64-bit SPARC, I think it's been 5 levels since the start, and I think 64-bit s390 and PPC also use 5 levels, but I'm not certain.

Comment: I believe the Intel processors supporting 5-level are not even released yet.

Comment: As of 2023, 5-level page tables are supported in [Ice Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Lake_(microprocessor)) and the kernel (v.6.1.6) by default also sets `X86_5LEVEL` to `y`.

Answer (score 3):

I checked the linux kernel codes and got something different to Austin's answer.

arch/x86/Kconfig

```
  config PGTABLE_LEVELS
        int
        default 5 if X86_5LEVEL
        default 4 if X86_64
        default 3 if X86_PAE
        default 2
```